# Can I put a tuple into an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I am wondering how to put a tuple into an array? or is it better to use arrays in array for the design of the program rather than a tuple in an array?
please advice me. thank you

Comment: Do you mean to make an array of tuples?  Or to make a tuple *into* an array?

Comment: Do you mean `list` on an actual `array`?

Comment: i just want to store value like text and ID into tuple or list but i want to check it with another for loop. instead of using a for loop in a for loop. i am thinking to use arrays in array. But was pretty confuse whether should i use tuples in list or lists in a list. I am not very good at designing the structure of the design therefore i am asking for advice and opinion

Comment: @iCezz After you ask a question, you should click the green checkbox next to the answer of your choice to mark it as "accepted". Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) is immutable. This means that once it's created, you can't modify it in-place. A [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list), on the other hand, is mutable -- meaning you can add elements, remove elements, and change elements in-place. A list has extra overhead, so only use a list if you need to modify the values.

You can create a list of tuples:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> list_of_tuples
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

or a list of lists:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> list_of_lists
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

The difference is that you can modify the elements in the list of lists:

```
>>> list_of_lists[0][0] = 7
>>> list_of_lists
[[7, 2], [3, 4]]
```

but not with the list of tuples:

```
>>> list_of_tuples[0][0] = 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

To iterate over a list of tuples:

```
>>> for (x,y) in list_of_tuples:
...    print x,y
... 
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: i just want to store value like text and ID into tuple or list but i want to check it with another for loop. instead of using a for loop in a for loop. i am thinking to use arrays in array. But was pretty confuse whether should i use tuples in list or lists in a list. I am not very good at designing the structure of the design therefore i am asking for advice and opinion

Comment: @iCezz I added an example of how you can easily iterate over a list of tuples without multiple for loops.

Comment: i think this is a good idea, in this case i can retrieve the value inside a tuple easily and faster without having worry that the data will be changed. thanks again

Answer (score 10):

if you are talking about `list`, you can put anything into it, even different types:

```
l=[10,(10,11,12),20,"test"]

l[0] = (1,2,3)
l.append((4,5))
l.extend((21,22)) #this one adds each element from the tuple
```

if you mean `array`, no python [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html)s don't support tuples.

Comment: thank you for the advice. this is what i mean tuple in an array. basicly it store many tuples in a list. but i thought tuples does not have method therefore i believe that it will add into the list. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [ ('b', i , "ff" ) for i in range(1,5)]
```

Comment: The OP asked for an array, but this returns a list.